# Phpmyadmin Access Issue

Tags: phpmyadmin, fedora

Can any one help me with this issues?

I have installed phpMyAdmin on my new fedora15 system using the command

yum -y install phpmyadmin

All the files were downloaded a stored in specific locations eg: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin, /var/lib/phpMyAdmin and also the config file is created at /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf.

But when I try to access phpMyAdmin from browser I get a popup asking me the username and 
password.

The popup says:

A username and password are being requested by http:/localhost. The site says: "phpMyAdmin localhost"

I expected the phpmyadmin login dialog box where we have phpmyadmin logo and the legend with  username password boxes. But it shows different things.

I tried a lot to login using my mysql username and password but it does not allow me to login.

Please help me with this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's standard HTTP basic auth

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. Can you please suggest me on how do I login, since I don't even know the default username/password for this http authentication.

Comment: This is not really a code question, is it? It might be better ontopic over at superuser...

Comment: I don't know; I've never used PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing authentication type  in `config.inc.php`

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.It is exactly the same as above in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php

Comment: do you use a blank password ?

Comment: Yes I do have a blank password for root

Comment: Try $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

Comment: Even the above does not work... here's how my config.inc.php file looks... 
http://192.10.250.224/phpmyadminissue.txt 
Also the link to my phpmyadmin url is as follows:
http://192.10.250.224/phpmyadmin

Comment: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php doesn't get read by the Fedora package for some reason. Neither does /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php or /var/lib/phpMyAdmin.inc.php.

Answer (score 0):

after install phpmyadmin, execute in a terminal

```
#mysql_secure_installation
```

when ask for a password, just hit return and follow the steps