# Cannot Connect To Mysql From PhpMyadmin On Centos7

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, centos, centos7

Os : `CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)`

Mysql Version : `mysql  Ver 8.0.18 for Linux on x86_64`

I installed Apache, Mysql, Php73, and Phpmyadmin and everything is OK: Apache is working, Php is working, and I can even login to MySQL with this command:
 `mysql -h localhost -u root -p  XXXX`.

However, when I want to login with phpmyadmin `192.xxx.xxx.xxx/phpmyadmin` and enter the same user name and password it says `Cannot log in to the MySQL server` .

I didn't change any Configuration Of PhpMyadmin. I only changed `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` file from :

```
...
 <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
 # Apache 2.4
<RequireAny>
Require ip 127.0.0.1
Require ip ::1
</RequireAny>

 </IfModule>
...
```

to :

```
 <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
 # Apache 2.4
# <RequireAny>
# Require ip 127.0.0.1
# Require ip ::1
# </RequireAny>
 Require all granted
 </IfModule>
```

Where could be the problem?

Comment: Are you working on a Virtual Machine? It sounds like network visibility problems. Have you tried to ping that IP?

Comment: yes , i open phpmyadmin on browser and its ok , and just say ``` Cannot log in to the MySQL server ``` , its not connecting issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a password issue. Did you try changing the password?

Could check this out as well...[Phpmyadmin Access Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396892/phpmyadmin-access-issue?rq=1)

Comment: yes i change it with this command ``` mysql_secure_installation  ``` but its not work , and try to change the user name and password in ``` /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php ```  and then restart the apache and mysql but its not work either.

Comment: I Craete New User and grant all privileges to it , and everything is ok with mysql command line but still can't login with php myadmin in browser.

Comment: I Feel Like , Mysql Not Connected To PhpMyadmin :|